# Reshape dataframe using pandas melt to get two value columns

Tags: python, pandas, melt

my data is in the following format

```
x = pd.DataFrame([
    {'date': '2011-01-01', 'col1': '1','col2': '5', 'A_Q': '1', 'A_W': 'aa', 'B_Q': '2', 'B_W': 'zz'},
    {'date': '2011-01-02', 'col1': '1','col2': '9', 'A_Q': '-1', 'A_W': 'bb', 'B_Q': '3', 'B_W': 'rr'},
    {'date': '2011-01-03', 'col1': '3','col2': '3', 'A_Q': '0', 'A_W': 'cc', 'B_Q': '4', 'B_W': 'vv'},
    {'date': '2011-02-04', 'col1': '4','col2': '1', 'A_Q': '3', 'A_W': 'dd', 'B_Q': '5', 'B_W': 'gg'},
])
```

```
    date      col1 col2 A_Q A_W  B_Q B_W
0   2011-01-01  1    5   1   aa   2  zz
1   2011-01-02  1    9   -1  bb   3  rr
2   2011-01-03  3    3   0   cc   4  vv
3   2011-02-04  4    1   3   dd   5  gg
```

I would like to reshape the dataframe using melt or similar functions, with two output value columns. Any ideas on how to do this without splitting the input array?

```
     date     col1 col2 VAR Q   W
0   2011-01-01  1   5   A   1   aa
1   2011-01-01  1   5   B   2   zz
2   2011-01-02  1   9   A   -1  bb
3   2011-01-02  1   9   B   3   rr
4   2011-01-03  3   3   A   0   cc
5   2011-01-03  3   3   B   4   vv
6   2011-01-04  4   1   A   3   dd
7   2011-01-04  4   1   B   5   gg
```

Answer (score 3):

First idea is create `MultiIndex` by split columns with `_` and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = x.set_index(['date','col1', 'col2'])
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)
df = df.stack(0).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_3':'VAR'})
print (df)
         date col1 col2 VAR   Q   W
0  2011-01-01    1    5   A   1  aa
1  2011-01-01    1    5   B   2  zz
2  2011-01-02    1    9   A  -1  bb
3  2011-01-02    1    9   B   3  rr
4  2011-01-03    3    3   A   0  cc
5  2011-01-03    3    3   B   4  vv
6  2011-02-04    4    1   A   3  dd
7  2011-02-04    4    1   B   5  gg
```

Or use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with rshape `stack` and [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(x,stubnames=["A","B"],
                       i=['date','col1', 'col2'],
                       j="new", sep="_",suffix=".*")
        .stack()
        .unstack(-2)
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={'level_3':'VAR'}))
print (df)
new        date col1 col2 VAR   Q   W
0    2011-01-01    1    5   A   1  aa
1    2011-01-01    1    5   B   2  zz
2    2011-01-02    1    9   A  -1  bb
3    2011-01-02    1    9   B   3  rr
4    2011-01-03    3    3   A   0  cc
5    2011-01-03    3    3   B   4  vv
6    2011-02-04    4    1   A   3  dd
7    2011-02-04    4    1   B   5  gg
```

Or swap values with `_` between first and last to last and first, so need only `wide_to_long`:

```
df1 = x.copy()
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.replace(r'(\w+)_(\w+)', r'\2_\1', regex=True)

#thank you sammywemmy for alternative
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_').str[::-1].str.join('_')

df1 = pd.wide_to_long(df1,stubnames=["Q","W"],
                        i=['date','col1', 'col2'],
                        j="VAR", sep="_",suffix=".*").reset_index()
print (df1)
         date col1 col2 VAR   Q   W
0  2011-01-01    1    5   A   1  aa
1  2011-01-01    1    5   B   2  zz
2  2011-01-02    1    9   A  -1  bb
3  2011-01-02    1    9   B   3  rr
4  2011-01-03    3    3   A   0  cc
5  2011-01-03    3    3   B   4  vv
6  2011-02-04    4    1   A   3  dd
7  2011-02-04    4    1   B   5  gg
```

Comment: A simpler option, in my opinion, would be : ``x.columns.str.split('_').str[::-1].str.join('_')`` ... instead of the regex

Answer (score 1):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
x.pivot_longer(index = ['date', 'col1', 'col2'], 
               names_to = ('VAR', '.value'), 
               names_sep='_', 
               sort_by_appearance=True)
 
         date col1 col2 VAR   Q   W
0  2011-01-01    1    5   A   1  aa
1  2011-01-01    1    5   B   2  zz
2  2011-01-02    1    9   A  -1  bb
3  2011-01-02    1    9   B   3  rr
4  2011-01-03    3    3   A   0  cc
5  2011-01-03    3    3   B   4  vv
6  2011-02-04    4    1   A   3  dd
7  2011-02-04    4    1   B   5  gg
```